# Install an app from a simple little Makefile?

Tags: macos, bash, dock, python

I have a simple little application written in Python that I mostly use on Linux, but I'd like to get it going on macOS too.  On Linux I have a Makefile to install it - it's not an rpm or a deb or anything like that.

Is there a way of just installing it from the Makefile on macOS too?

On Linux, I'm using desktop-file-install to install the application, which is just a few .py's, a little shell, and an icon file as an SVG or PNG.  I found dockutil on macOS in homebrew, which looks kind of similar, but it seems to want to use a preexisting .app directory under /Applications.

What's the easiest (read: no clickitis) way to automatically add an application to the dock on macOS, if you just have a few python and bash scripts and an icon file?

Thanks!

PS: I'm likely the only person in the world using this, so there's not much point in creating a .dmg or something.

Comment: Do you mean a full Apple gui app or are you just using app as a term for a unix executable?

Comment: @mmmmmm It's a GUI application written using https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html , and seems to run OK on Mac (maybe a little slow? Also I have to click an extra time).

Comment: I think from https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/deploy.html you need to look at gtk-mac-bundler

Comment: If you have the XCode command line utilities installed you can use the make file to make/install the program. If there are any dependencies for python you have to install them using pip. After that you should be able to run the program from the MacOS terminal. If you require a clickable icon you can wrap the startup command and it’s parameters in into a small wrapper using e.g. platypus -> https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus